# Column method return type in TreeBasedTable

Tags: java, guava, treemap

According to [javadocs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html), TreeBaseTable is an

> Implementation of Table whose row keys and column keys are ordered by their natural ordering or by supplied comparators.

Consistently, both `row(R rowKey)` and `rowMap()` methods return a `SortedMap`.

On the other hand `column(C columnKey)` returns only a `Map`. Bearing in mind that all these methods return a view of the underlying mappings, is it safe to assume that also this one keeps the original sort order?

Answer (score 0):

That should be safe to assume. We have [at least one test](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/1eb9f7dc7ae032be53db39d107e0b74dbc810f26/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/collect/TableCollectionTest.java#L575) that I've confirmed will fail if we break change this behavior. Would you mind [filing an issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/new) for us to document the guarantee?